# How Nimai became Chaitanya?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism

Chaitanya Dev was the founder of the Gaudiya Vaishnavism. His original name was Bishwambhar. But people around him used to call him Nimai, his pet name. How did he get his new name, "Chaitanya Dev"?

Answer (score 1):

Nimai took Sannyas from Keshav Bharati in Katwa (West Bengal). After the initiation, Keshav Bharati gave Nimai the new name "Sri Krishna Chaitanya." It literally means Krishna consciousness.

Reference:

Chaitanya Mahaprabhu: the Story of Bengal's Greatest Bhakti Saint by Chitrita Banerjee